# How can i get value using data.get() function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of a textarea that I have append into a fieldset of my form.
To do so, when I submit my form, the following code is triggered:

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById('Observation_1').value);
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  const value = data.get('Observation_1');
  console.log(value);
}
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="Observation_1"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

however, my `console.log (value);` returns me *null*, while my `console.log(document.getElementById('Observation_1').value);`
return me the content of my textarea.

Can someone explain me why i have a null return and help me to fix my code so i can get the actual content of my textarea please.

Comment: Forms require `name` on controls that need to be included in submission or FormData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have a `name="Observation_1"` attribute on the textarea.

Comment: that's right, sorry for the stupid question and thanks for your help

Comment: @N_G [There is no such thing as a stupid question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question).